# Switching from ListView to the RecyclerView

Tags: listview, android-recyclerview

I want to change my `ListView` into a `RecyclerView`. Here is my main activity:

```
Button btnAdd, btnGetAll;
TextView note_Id;

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnAdd)) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("note_Id", 0);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else {

        NoteRepo repo = new NoteRepo(this);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> noteList = repo.getNoteList();
        if (noteList.size() != 0) {
            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    note_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note_Id);
                    String noteId = note_Id.getText().toString();
                    Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteDetail.class);
                    objIndent.putExtra("note_Id", Integer.parseInt(noteId));
                    startActivity(objIndent);
                }
            });
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, noteList, R.layout.view_note_entry, new String[]{"id", "title"}, new int[]{R.id.note_Id, R.id.note_title});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No note!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnGetAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetAll);
    btnGetAll.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Here is my `NoteDetail` class:

```
Button btnSave ,  btnDelete;
Button btnClose;
EditText editTextTitle;
EditText editTextNote;
private int _Note_Id=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_detail);

    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

    editTextTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
    editTextNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNote);

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(this);


    _Note_Id =0;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    _Note_Id =intent.getIntExtra("note_Id", 0);
    NoteRepo repo = new NoteRepo(this);
    Note note = new Note();
    note = repo.getNoteById(_Note_Id);

    editTextTitle.setText(note.title);
    editTextNote.setText(note.note);
}



public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnSave)){
        NoteRepo repo = new NoteRepo(this);
        Note note = new Note();
        note.note=editTextNote.getText().toString();
        note.title=editTextTitle.getText().toString();
        note.note_ID=_Note_Id;

        if (_Note_Id==0){
            _Note_Id = repo.insert(note);

            Toast.makeText(this,"New Note Insert",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{

            repo.update(note);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Note Record updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }else if (view== findViewById(R.id.btnDelete)){
        NoteRepo repo = new NoteRepo(this);
        repo.delete(_Note_Id);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Note Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        finish();
    }else if (view== findViewById(R.id.btnClose)){
        finish();
    }


}
```

Here is my `NoteRepo` class:

```
public NoteRepo(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
}

public int insert(Note note) {

    //Open connection to write data
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Note.KEY_note,note.note);
    values.put(Note.KEY_title, note.title);

    // Inserting Row
    long note_Id = db.insert(Note.TABLE, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
    return (int) note_Id;
}

public void delete(int note_Id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    // It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string
    db.delete(Note.TABLE, Note.KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(note_Id) });
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

public void update(Note note) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Note.KEY_note,note.note);
    values.put(Note.KEY_title, note.title);

    // It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string
    db.update(Note.TABLE, values, Note.KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(note.note_ID) });
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  getNoteList() {
    //Open connection to read only
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery =  "SELECT  " +
            Note.KEY_ID + "," +
            Note.KEY_title + "," +
            Note.KEY_note +
            " FROM " + Note.TABLE;

    //Note note = new Note();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> noteList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> note = new HashMap<String, String>();
            note.put("id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.KEY_ID)));
            note.put("title", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.KEY_title)));
            noteList.add(note);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return noteList;

}

public Note getNoteById(int Id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery =  "SELECT  " +
            Note.KEY_ID + "," +
            Note.KEY_title + "," +
            Note.KEY_note +
            " FROM " + Note.TABLE
            + " WHERE " +
            Note.KEY_ID + "=?";// It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string

    int iCount =0;
    Note note = new Note();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { String.valueOf(Id) } );

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            note.note_ID =cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.KEY_ID));
            note.title =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.KEY_title));
            note.note  =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.KEY_note));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return note;
}
```

Here is my `DBHelper` class:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "crud.db";

public DBHelper(Context context ) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //All necessary tables you like to create will create here

    String CREATE_TABLE_NOTE = "CREATE TABLE " + Note.TABLE  + "("
            + Note.KEY_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
            + Note.KEY_title + " TEXT, "
            + Note.KEY_note + " TEXT )";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NOTE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed, all data will be gone!!!
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Note.TABLE);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}
```

How do I switch to the `RecyclerView` and still maintain accessibility to my database? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please attach your layout file for the items into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RecyclerView` is a very efficient view to display a large set of items. According to the [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) website, a `RecyclerView` is:

> A flexible view for providing a limited window into a large data set.

Assuming that you already have an existing layout file used in the `ListView`, you can easily link it with the `RecyclerView`. In your main activity layout file, type:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

> **I am unable to build my app and get errors when I add the above code**
>
> You may need to compile a dependency like so:
>
> `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'`

You will now need to create a `RecyclerView.Adapter` class. Create a new Java class and call it `RecyclerViewAdapter.java`. Add the following code into it:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
    public Context context;
    public List<RecyclerViewList> list;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<RecyclerViewList> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView note;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_title);
            note = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_note);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file, viewGroup, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ListsListHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.title.setText(list.get(position).title);
        viewHolder.note.setText(list.get(position).note);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Once you have created the class, you will need to create a new class for the `List<>`. Create a new Java class and called it `RecyclerViewList.java`. Add the following code into it:

```
public class RecyclerViewList {
    public String title;
    public String note;

    public RecyclerViewList(String title, String note) {
        this.title = title;
        this.note = note;
    }
}
```

In your `NoteRepo.java` file, change the function `getNoteList` to this:

```
public Cursor getNoteList() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 

    return db.query(Note.TABLE, new String[] {Note.KEY_ID, Note.KEY_title, Note.KEY_note}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

In your main activity Java class, below the class declaration, add the following code:

```
private List<RecyclerViewList> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

In your `onCreate` event, add the following code:

```
NoteRepo repo = new NoteRepo(this);

Cursor cursor = repo.getNoteList();

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        list.add(new RecyclerViewList(cursor.getString(column), cursor.getString(column)));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}


RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, list);

recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Make sure you instantiate your list with all of the items from your database with the code that you already have. If you have any issues, please ask in the comments below.